# Having trouble with packets not making it into Fedora 16 Apache

Tags: fedora, iptables, routing

Background: I haven't done anything with `iptables` in a few years... I have Fedora 16 running in a VM on VMWare, with my firewall (TomatoUSB) port forwarding to the VM.

VM is at `192.168.1.155`. I know that the packets are making it to the VM...

Based on [this illustration](http://linux-ip.net/pages/diagrams.html#netfilter-kernel-packet-traversal) to see how the packets are supposed to go, I would expect the packets to come out of `nat-PREROUTING` and either go to `mangle-INPUT` or `mangle-FORWARD` unless the kernel is dropping them for some other reason.

So I turned on some logging:

```
iptables -t mangle -v -A PREROUTING -j LOG -p tcp --destination-port 80 --log-prefix 'mangle-PREROUTING '
iptables -t nat -v -A PREROUTING -j LOG -p tcp --destination-port 80 --log-prefix 'nat-PREROUTING '
iptables -t filter -v -I INPUT 1 -j LOG -p tcp --destination-port 80 --log-prefix 'filter-INPUT '
iptables -t filter -v -I FORWARD 1 -j LOG -p tcp --destination-port 80 --log-prefix 'filter-FORWARD '
iptables -t mangle -v -I INPUT 1 -j LOG -p tcp --destination-port 80 --log-prefix 'mangle-INPUT ' 
iptables -t mangle -v -I FORWARD 1 -j LOG -p tcp --destination-port 80 --log-prefix 'mangle-FORWARD '
```

and then I used an [external test service](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) and I can see the packets coming in past the `PREROUTING` chains, but then being ignored:

```
Apr 23 19:11:52 webmail64 kernel: [  351.116042] mangle-PREROUTING IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:fa:36:c7:bc:ae:c5:c3:68:f9:08:00 SRC=66.249.67.195 DST=192.168.1.155 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=48 ID=20466 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=64135 DPT=80 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Apr 23 19:11:52 webmail64 kernel: [  351.121701] nat-PREROUTING IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:fa:36:c7:bc:ae:c5:c3:68:f9:08:00 SRC=66.249.67.195 DST=192.168.1.155 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=48 ID=20466 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=64135 DPT=80 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Apr 23 19:11:55 webmail64 kernel: [  354.113372] mangle-PREROUTING IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:fa:36:c7:bc:ae:c5:c3:68:f9:08:00 SRC=66.249.67.195 DST=192.168.1.155 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=48 ID=20467 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=64135 DPT=80 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Apr 23 19:11:55 webmail64 kernel: [  354.114834] nat-PREROUTING IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:fa:36:c7:bc:ae:c5:c3:68:f9:08:00 SRC=66.249.67.195 DST=192.168.1.155 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=48 ID=20467 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=64135 DPT=80 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Apr 23 19:12:01 webmail64 kernel: [  360.109534] mangle-PREROUTING IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:fa:36:c7:bc:ae:c5:c3:68:f9:08:00 SRC=66.249.67.195 DST=192.168.1.155 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=48 ID=20468 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=64135 DPT=80 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Apr 23 19:12:01 webmail64 kernel: [  360.111023] nat-PREROUTING IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:fa:36:c7:bc:ae:c5:c3:68:f9:08:00 SRC=66.249.67.195 DST=192.168.1.155 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=48 ID=20468 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=64135 DPT=80 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

You can see that `TTL` is fine. The VM's IP is `192.168.1.155` so it should go to `INPUT` next but it never makes it. If the packet came from inside my network, it is as expected:

```
Apr 23 19:20:03 webmail64 kernel: [  841.725402] mangle-PREROUTING IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:fa:36:c7:00:1f:3b:cb:2e:99:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.69 DST=192.168.1.155 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=4562 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=61520 DPT=80 WINDOW=4042 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Apr 23 19:20:03 webmail64 kernel: [  841.729647] mangle-INPUT IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:fa:36:c7:00:1f:3b:cb:2e:99:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.69 DST=192.168.1.155 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=4562 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=61520 DPT=80 WINDOW=4042 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Apr 23 19:20:03 webmail64 kernel: [  841.731056] filter-INPUT IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:fa:36:c7:00:1f:3b:cb:2e:99:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.69 DST=192.168.1.155 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=4562 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=61520 DPT=80 WINDOW=4042 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Apr 23 19:20:03 webmail64 kernel: [  841.732784] mangle-PREROUTING IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:fa:36:c7:00:1f:3b:cb:2e:99:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.69 DST=192.168.1.155 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=4563 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=61520 DPT=80 WINDOW=4042 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Apr 23 19:20:03 webmail64 kernel: [  841.734257] mangle-INPUT IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:fa:36:c7:00:1f:3b:cb:2e:99:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.69 DST=192.168.1.155 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=4563 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=61520 DPT=80 WINDOW=4042 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Apr 23 19:20:03 webmail64 kernel: [  841.735676] filter-INPUT IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:fa:36:c7:00:1f:3b:cb:2e:99:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.69 DST=192.168.1.155 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=4563 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=61520 DPT=80 WINDOW=4042 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

What have I tried?

- Turned off SELinux
- Totally turned off `iptables`
- Ensured that the default policies are `ACCEPT`

  - Saw that the packet counts for the `ACCEPT` incremented
- Turned on IP forwarding (`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`) just in case

My setup:
 * `kernel` = `Linux webmail64 3.3.2-1.fc16.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Apr 14 00:31:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
 * `iptables v1.4.12`

Here are all the `iptables` in case it matters:

```
[root@webmail64 ~]# iptables-save 
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Mon Apr 23 20:47:24 2012
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [916:127527]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:60]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [87:7857]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [87:7857]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j LOG --log-prefix "nat-PREROUTING "
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Apr 23 20:47:24 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Mon Apr 23 20:47:24 2012
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1402:193108]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1343:189856]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [303:67789]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [303:67789]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j LOG --log-prefix "mangle-PREROUTING "
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j LOG --log-prefix "mangle-INPUT "
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j LOG --log-prefix "mangle-FORWARD "
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Apr 23 20:47:24 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Mon Apr 23 20:47:24 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1075:220262]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j LOG --log-prefix "filter-INPUT "
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j LOG --log-prefix "filter-FORWARD "
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Apr 23 20:47:24 2012
```

Where can I look next?

## Update

I was asked to run `tcpdump` and it looks like I am never sending `ACK` packets?:

```
tcpdump -i eth1 -An -vvv \(net 50 or net 173\)
tcpdump: listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
19:31:26.305048 IP (tos 0x20, ttl 53, id 26094, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    50.22.90.226.48891 > 192.168.1.155.http: Flags [S], cksum 0xca12 (correct), seq 2918539684, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1152517194 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E .<e.@.5..r2.Z........P..a....................
D..J........
19:31:26.521815 IP (tos 0x20, ttl 53, id 61033, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    50.22.90.226.48892 > 192.168.1.155.http: Flags [S], cksum 0x82b4 (correct), seq 1826089481, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1152517216 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E .<.i@.5...2.Z........Pl..     ...................
D..`........
19:31:29.300994 IP (tos 0x20, ttl 53, id 26095, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    50.22.90.226.48891 > 192.168.1.155.http: Flags [S], cksum 0xc8e6 (correct), seq 2918539684, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1152517494 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E .<e.@.5..q2.Z........P..a....................
D..v........
19:31:29.521214 IP (tos 0x20, ttl 53, id 61034, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    50.22.90.226.48892 > 192.168.1.155.http: Flags [S], cksum 0x8188 (correct), seq 1826089481, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1152517516 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E .<.j@.5...2.Z........Pl..     ...................
D...........
19:31:35.302578 IP (tos 0x20, ttl 53, id 26096, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    50.22.90.226.48891 > 192.168.1.155.http: Flags [S], cksum 0xc68e (correct), seq 2918539684, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1152518094 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E .<e.@.5..p2.Z........P..a....................
D...........
19:31:35.532347 IP (tos 0x20, ttl 53, id 61035, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    50.22.90.226.48892 > 192.168.1.155.http: Flags [S], cksum 0x7f2f (correct), seq 1826089481, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1152518117 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E .<.k@.5...2.Z........Pl..     ........./.........
D...........
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late, however ... Does the host *know* it is responsible that IP? Here's a schema I put at the top of the rules files I create. You can find similar flow-charts elsewhere, but having it in ASCII (wouldn't want to call it art ;)) can be quite useful on the terminal.

For the most part I know this from heart, but hey, doesn't hurt to have a reference if forgetfulness strikes.

```
###############################################################################
###
###            PACKET FLOW THROUGH NETFILTER TABLES AND CHAINS
###
###
###                          {Packet in}
###                               |
###                               v
###                       +-----------------+
###                       |mangle/PREROUTING|
###                       +-----------------+
###                               |
###                               v
###                       +-----------------+
###                       |  nat/PREROUTING |
###                       +-----------------+
###                               |
###                               v
###                       *~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*
###                       |  kernel routing |
###                       *~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*
###                               |
###                               v
###           .------------{?for this host?}------------.
###      yes! |                                         | no!
###           v                                         v
###  +-----------------+                       +-----------------+
###  |   mangle/INPUT  |                       |  mangle/FORWARD |
###  +-----------------+                       +-----------------+
###           |                                         |
###           v                                         v
###  +-----------------+                       +-----------------+
###  |   filter/INPUT  |                       |  filter/FORWARD |
###  +-----------------+                       +-----------------+
###           |                                         |
###           v                                         |
### *~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*                              |
### | response & routing |                              |
### *~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*                              |
###           |                                         |
###           v                                         |
###  +-----------------+                                |
###  |  mangle/OUTPUT  |                                |
###  +-----------------+                                |
###           |                                         |
###           v                                         |
###  +-----------------+                                |
###  |    nat/OUTPUT   |                                |
###  +-----------------+                                |
###           |                                         |
###           v                                         |
###  +-----------------+                                |
###  |  filter/OUTPUT  |                                |
###  +-----------------+                                |
###           |                                         |
###           .-------------------+---------------------.
###                               |
###                               v
###                      +------------------+
###                      |mangle/POSTROUTING|
###                      +------------------+
###                               |
###                               v
###                      +------------------+
###                      |  nat/POSTROUTING |
###                      +------------------+
###                               |
###                               v
###                          {Packet out}
###
###############################################################################
```

Now what does that mean?

Routing can happen either using the routing table ("kernel routing" in the above flowchart) or using netfilter. Now if - and that's the most likely scenario in your case - you didn't set up the routing table accordingly, the kernel would not know where the packet has to go and eventually drop it. Btw: in such cases it's useful to create a custom chain that will `LOG` and then `DROP` or add the rules in that order. This way you'll see what rules were hit. Also useful is `iptables-save -c` which will prepend the packet and byte counters to each rule line similar to how it appends it for the chains (format `[packets:bytes]`).

For ports forwarded to a VM via `DNAT` I have the following recipe (will explain below):

```
#!/bin/bash
VMNET=192.168.1.0/24
MAINIP=66.249.67.195
CONTIP=192.168.1.2
VMPORT=80
INPORT=80
ACTION="-I"
iptables -t nat    $ACTION PREROUTING  -d $MAINIP -p tcp --dport $INPORT -j DNAT --to-destination $CONTIP:$VMPORT
iptables -t nat    $ACTION POSTROUTING -s $VMNET ! -d $VMNET -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
iptables -t nat    $ACTION POSTROUTING -s $VMNET ! -d $VMNET -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
iptables -t nat    $ACTION POSTROUTING -s $VMNET ! -d $VMNET -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t filter $ACTION INPUT       -p tcp -d $MAINIP --dport $INPORT -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter $ACTION FORWARD     -p tcp --dport $INPORT -d $VMNET -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter $ACTION FORWARD     -p tcp --dport $INPORT -d $MAINIP -j ACCEPT
```

Mind that you may want to alter the order to fit the rules with your own. Also, if the `OUTPUT` chain doesn't have `ACCEPT` as its default policy, make sure that you add an output rule, although for all practical purposes this should be catered by having an `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` state rule. You can also refine the interfaces to match or match by wildcard. For example I gave the bridges of my virtual guests all the prefix `_` (an underscore) and can therefore match `-i _+` and `-o _+`. Similarly for several network cards (`eth0`, `eth1`) you'd match with `-i eth+`.

So what happens here is that:

1. a `DNAT` rule is inserted which takes input on (host) port `$INPORT` for TCP and "routes" it to `$CONTIP:$VMPORT`, i.e. the IP of the container and the port in the container. Yep, they could differ. If they don't it's alright to leave out the destination part (i.e. just ``$CONTIP`).
2. three rules to mask traffic that's *from* the subnet of the virtual guests but not going *to* another virtual guest.
3. an `INPUT` rule to allow incoming packets on the public IP (no interface given, but could be!) to port `$INPORT` through. I think this rule isn't strictly needed, at least not if you tie it to the public interface.
4. a rule to forward traffic to `$INPORT` for the virtual guest subnet (`$VMNET`)
5. a rule to forward traffic to `$INPORT` on the public IP (`$MAINIP`)

Last but not least the value for `sysctl` (`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`) should be:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

to make your host a router.

If it's not use `echo 1` to write to the above "file" in the `procfs` or better yet use `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` as `root`.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know *why* but I got it to work.

I had two interfaces, `eth0` (192.168.99.x) and `eth1` (192.168.1.x). They were there for legacy reasons, I was lazy when I wanted a new VM and copied my previous one. Anyway, I simply disabled `eth0` and everything worked.

I checked some of the `rp_filter` settings in `/etc/sysctl.conf` but that didn't fix it (but made me think it was a weird IF issue). The settings are documented in `/usr/share/doc/kernel-doc-x.x.x/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt` in the `kernel-doc` package.

So it works now, and I will leave this here for the search engines to find and maybe this will help somebody else some day.